# binomial simulation inside an if-else statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to create some data.  First I want to flip 40 fair coins.  For each coin that lands heads, or 1, I want to flip another fair coin.

I thought that using `rbinom` inside an `ifelse` statement would work, but I am getting what seem like odd results.

Here is my code where `aa` represents the results of flipping the first 40 coins and `cc` I thought represents the results of flipping a second coin for each coin in `aa` that landed heads.

I repeat the `ifelse` statement several times below and get one of two results.  The first result for `cc` matches that of `aa` and the second result is all 0's.  These results are perplexing.  Thank you for any advice or explanation of what is happening.

```
set.seed(1234)

aa <- rbinom(40, 1, 0.5) ; aa
# [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
cc <- ifelse(aa == 1, rbinom(1, 1, 0.5), 0) ; cc
# [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
cc <- ifelse(aa == 1, rbinom(1, 1, 0.5), 0) ; cc
# [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
cc <- ifelse(aa == 1, rbinom(1, 1, 0.5), 0) ; cc
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
cc <- ifelse(aa == 1, rbinom(1, 1, 0.5), 0) ; cc
# [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
cc <- ifelse(aa == 1, rbinom(1, 1, 0.5), 0) ; cc
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
cc <- ifelse(aa == 1, rbinom(1, 1, 0.5), 0) ; cc
# [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is probably not ideal because a "tails" flip and no flip (because `aa==0`) result in the same output (0). Also, your second flip is only providing one flip rather than a vector of flips, thus the reason why all of your `cc` results are either the same sequence of 0's and 1's or all 0 (depending on whether the second flip is 1 or 0, respectively). Try:

```
cc <- ifelse(aa == 1, rbinom(length(aa), 1, 0.5), NA); cc
```

Comment: Thank you.  For some reason I was thinking my code would call rbinom once each time aa == 1.

Comment: That approach could be obtained with something like: `sapply(aa, function(i) ifelse(i==1, rbinom(1,1,0.5), NA))`

Answer (score 1):

It appears that R is really lazy when it comes to evaluating the ifelse statement, so it is only calling rbinom(1,1,0.5) *once*!

```
cc <- ifelse(aa == 1, rbinom(1,1,0.5), 0)
```

is the equivalent of:

```
cc <- aa
cc[cc == 1] <- rbinom(1,1,0.5)
```

I had a play around, and the only way to get R to call rbinom multiple times is to do it in a for loop:

```
set.seed(1234)
aa <- rbinom(40, 1, 0.5); aa
# [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
cc <- aa
for (i in seq_along(cc)) {
    cc[i] <- ifelse(cc[i] == 1, rbinom(1,1,0.5), 0)
}
cc
#  [1] 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: Actually just read Thomas's reply. His method will work too, allowing for a clever succinct solution:
`cc <- as.numeric(aa & rbinom(1,1,0.5))`

Comment: I don't think it's so much "lazy" as that `ifelse` calculates the full vector of values for both outcomes prior to evaluating the input vector.  That is, for `a<-1:10; b<-ifelse(a>5,a+5,a-5)` , I think the full `a+5` and `a-5` vectors are calculated first, and the selections made as "if" traverses the values of `a>5` .  Since binom(1,1,.5) returns a single value, it's automagically repeated to the length of `a` , as with most `R` functions.

Comment: followup:  Edit: peeking at the code for `ifelse`, this is exactly what happens

Comment: I may be misunderstanding vectorization, but it's lazy evaluation in the functional programming sense?

Comment: I don't think so.  If I understand "lazy eval" in `R` it means that objects are not evaluated until some statement actually calls upon them.  Not what's happening here.